# "No D-BUS daemon running" when running phpunit test

Tags: php, firefox, selenium, functional-testing, dbus

When I run my "`selenium`" tests, `firefox` displays the following window:

[image]

Should I ignore it? Is there a way to fix it? I'm running `firefox-38.0.5` and `selenium-2.46.0`. `selenium` starts `firefox` this way:

```
/usr/bin/firefox -profile /tmp/customProfileDire84f0e898d9c43d39dededa75b0dea22
```

**UPD**

```
dbus       413     1  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
yuri      3994     1  0 Jun21 tty1     00:00:00 dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session
yuri      3995     1  0 Jun21 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
yuri      6639  6636  0 Jun21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
yuri     13082  5986  0 22:16 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/bash -c ps -ef | grep dbus
yuri     13084 13082  0 22:16 pts/4    00:00:00 grep dbus
```

**UPD** I've just found out that this happens when I run tests under `tmux`. Additionally, I set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to `~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock`, so that I could make `tmux` communicate with other `ssh-agent` without restarting `tmux`. And the related issue is that `svn` can't access GNOME keyring, asks for password every time under `tmux`.

Comment: Just to be sure. D-Bus is running?

Comment: @Shelltux I suppose yes, see my updated answer.

Comment: What happens if you run `dbus-launch [YourFireFoxExec]`?

Comment: @Shelltux When I run `dbus-launch firefox` no such dialog appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issues has to do with `tmux` not updating environment variables (not that it can). They manifest itself after restarting windows manager (exiting and starting it again) and leaving `tmux` running. As a result, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` changes its value, but processes running inside `tmux` has still the old value of the variable. One option would probably be to create a symlink to the file, however I can't see it (e.g., `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-JVndBgLlIC,guid=f9f24c9f9cdbd6648f38035e5598b880`). The other is to update the variable manually for each process needing it. Additionally, one can add the variable to `tmux`'s `update-environment` option, so that new windows get the right value.

The same thing causes `svn` unable to communicate to `GNOME Keyring`.

Link to [the forum discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1542400), just in case.